# % gets removed from URL when triggered from A element

Tags: html

I  have a problem which I can't find the answer for on Google.

I have the following link on my website:

```
<a href="/search?Category%5B%5D=Apartments+And+Penthouses">APPARTMENTS</a>
```

When clicked the URL (in the browser) looks like this:

> http://example.com/search?Category5D=Apartments+And+Penthouses

So it is removing the % from the href link, which breaks my search engine. How do I force the A tag to not remove the `%`?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @gargkshitiz The exact link that is in the href.

Comment: Can you make any demo of this ? I don't get your problem ?

Comment: the problem is: when he clicks on the `a`, this part of the link `%5B%` is being cutted off...

Comment: @user2486 I can't make a working example. The problem is that the url that gets triggered when I click the A tag, is different from what is in the HREF. The % from %5D% gets removed for some reason.

Comment: Its strange. I guess server side is expecting `?Category[]=Apartments+And+Penthouses` as `%5B` is `[` , and `%5D` is `]`. which browser is it?

Comment: @gargkshitiz Its chrome. The filter system works perfectly fine if its dynamic but as soon as i trigger it from a <a> tag it gets changed.

Comment: Try playing around here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_test.

Comment: @gargkshitiz I don't know why that would help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that % straight into the URL is not possible, I had to use unicode or HTML code for it to work.

`&#37;` = %

The link should be:

> /search?Category%5B%5D=Apartments+And+Penthouses

The CMS I am using, uses %....% as placeholders, getting filled with pre defined values. I guess it did not like having % % in the URL.

Comment: Hm, it seem like a quite strange solution of your mysterious problem: normally there is nothing wrong with using `%` directly in link `href` value in HTML.  Using entity instead of percent character is fine workaround, but should not be necessary.  I suspect that something around your application tries to interpolate `%...%` sequences and silently outputs empty strings.  Or messes with percent URI encoding.  I'd really like to know what the real reason was…

Comment: The CMS I am using indeed uses %...% as placeholders that get filled by specific values. As I did not develop this CMS and am only a student webdeveloper. I had not thought about this causing such problems.

Comment: Ah, it makes much more sense now; I think it would be worth mentioning in the answer, even better if you could disclose and add the CMS / templating engine name and tag it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be either

- in the page: JavaScript alteration - inspect the link and try the page with JavaScript disabled, in anonymous tab,
- or on your server: unwanted redirect - watch network console.

You should see `[]` in the URL.

```html
<p><a href="http://example.com/?keys%5B%5D=val">..%5B%5D..</a>

<p><a href="http://example.com/?keys[]=val">..[]..</a>
```

Comment: If `anonymous tab` means incognito it doesn't work with that either. Also network console does not show anything wierd that i can see.

Comment: And if you run snippet above and interact with links there, do they work OK? You should see `http://example.com/?keys[]=val` in statusbar before clicking and in URL bar after navigation. if you see `http://example.com/?keys5D=val` instead, then there is someting really strange…

Comment: The snippet does not do anything. Also when i try to run it on the server nothing happends either. Its the same link as i put into the href.